# How do I create a Dictionary<string,string> for nested object

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am retrieving the following JSON via a POST to an API

```
{
    "State":"Andhra_Pradesh",
    "District":"Guntur", 
    "Fact":"SELECT", 
    "Description":"",
    "FactDate":"",
    "FactNumber":"",
    "FactType":"SELECT",
    "Fact":{"Id":"1"}
}
```

I am able to execute the Ajax request via javascript, but I also want to consume the API through C# code.

I am using the below code, but I'm not quite sure on how to add the Fact object?

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "State", selectedState },
                { "District", selectedDistrict },
                { "Fact", ""},
                { "FactType", ""},
                { "FactNumber", ""},
                { "Description", ""},
                {"Fact", "{Id,1}" },
                {"FactDate", factDate.Date.ToString() }
            };

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                { 
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values); 
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("http://api.in/" + "test", content);
}
```

How do I add the Fact object to Dictionary?

Comment: I am not familiar with this field but I suppose you should write `"{Id:1}"` instead of `"{Id,1}"`?

Comment: What you're asking is not impossible, but I would advise against using a `Dictionary<string,string>` here. Once your JSON object is no longer just a flat list of properties and starts having nested properties etc, you'll be much better off defining a custom class that matches your expected JSON object. This also removes the need to find properties by index (string) lookup, and makes them directly accessible through defined properties. Your current question can be answered but it seems like a bad approach in your context.

Comment: Why don't you use Json format?

Comment: @Sweeper "{Id:1}" did not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to define the data you are sending as actual class before using httpclient.

If you had only name value pairs then you could have used the NameValueCollection and sent as a formurlencoded but since you have a complex type, you might consider this below.

See below.

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public Fact Fact { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CaseDate { get; set; }
    public string FactNumber { get; set; }
    public string FactType { get; set; }
}

public class Fact
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Usage is as below. be sure to include a reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll`

```
var client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


    var model = new Rootobject { State = "Andhra_Pradesh", District = "Guntur", FactType = "SELECT", Description = "", CaseDate = "", FactNumber = "", Fact = new Fact { Id = "1"} };

    var data = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://api.in/" + "test", model);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a json object, you can either create a class which have the same properties of (state, district etc ..) and use [json serializer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/)

or you can create [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDynamic.htm) using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Newtonsonft.Json` to to the serializaton/deserialization job and the code will be like that.

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        [JsonProperty("State")]
        public string State { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("District")]
        public string District { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Fact")]
        public Fact Fact { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("CaseDate")]
        public string CaseDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("FactNumber")]
        public string FactNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("FactType")]
        public string FactType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fact
    {
        [JsonProperty("Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

And then, after instatiating your object, just serialize it.

```
Rootobject example = new Rootobject();
//Add values to the variable example.
var objectSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(example);
```

After that, you will have a json ready to be send wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `{"Fact", "{Id,1}" }` to `{"Fact.Id", "1" },`